# Inverting Proofs using "Iff"s

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Before you read my question, let me make it clear that I am *new* to proof theory and know *almost nothing* about it. This is just something that I thought of out of the blue.

When one writes a proof, the proof consists of a chain of statements that imply each other. For example, a proof of the statement $S_1 \implies S_n$ might look like
$$S_1\implies S_2\implies ...\implies S_n$$
Where each of the theorems used in the proof of this theorem are the theorems
$$S_1\implies S_2$$
$$S_2\implies S_3$$
$$...$$
$$S_{n-1}\implies S_n$$
Which must be established beforehand

If you wanted to prove that $S_1 \iff S_n$, (I will call this type of theorem a "symmetric theorem", for lack of a better term) you can write proofs for both $S_1\implies S_n$ and $S_n\implies S_1$. However, you can achieve this in a single proof by instead using a proof that looks like this:
$$S_1\iff S_2\iff ...\iff S_n$$
Because to prove the converse, instead of starting a separate proof, you can just turn this proof "backwards" and it will still work, since all of the intermediate theorems are symmetric.

However, I am trying to prove that if a theorem is symmetric, then it *must have a proof* using all symmetric intermediate theorems. It seems fairly obvious, but how do I show that? Assume the opposite and look for a contradiction?

I thought that this would be an interesting thing to prove, because I believe that if it were true, it would imply that in a formal system with *no symmetric axioms*, no symmetric theorems can be proven to be true.

Also, can anybody point me towards any resources addressing this kind of thing? Perhaps a beginning course of proof theory?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean to prove that : $$(S_1 \Leftrightarrow S_n) \Rightarrow (S_n\Leftrightarrow S_i, \forall i \in [1,n])$$ ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what it boils down to.

Comment: What is a symmetric axiom?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I'm using it to refer to a theorem that "works forwards and backwards", or uses "if and only if".

Comment: Theorem: $\;\forall x\;(x=x)\iff \forall y\;(y=y).$ Axioms needed: None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say that your symmetric theorem is of the form $S_1 \Leftrightarrow S_n$ you are basically already assuming that there are already a bunch of intermediate results $S_i$ ... all standing in the $S_i \Leftrightarrow S_{i+1}$ relationship. I mean, why else do you have those indices?

So maybe that's not a very interesting question....

And maybe a more interesting question is: if we have a symmetric theorem $\varphi \Leftrightarrow \psi$, will it always be the case that there are statements $S_1 ... S_n$ such that there is a symmetrical proof $\varphi = S_1 \Leftrightarrow S_2 ... \Leftrightarrow S_n = \psi$?   And, since we could of could of trivially course choose $S_1=\varphi$ and $S_2 = \psi$, let's make the restriction that $S_i \Leftrightarrow S_{i+1}$ must be  a specific instance of some rule of our proof system.

Well, it turns out that there are in fact *equivalence rules* that are complete for both propositional logic and predicate logic, meaning that whenever you have $\varphi \Leftrightarrow \psi$, you are guaranteed to be able to step by step transform $\varphi$ into $\psi$ using the equivalence rules, and since those are equivalence rules, such a transformation counts as a symmetric proof.

If you only have *inference rules*, however (such as what most natural deduction systems have), then typically you cannot invert the proof, and you will have to give two proofs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so let's try to prove $$(S_1 \Leftrightarrow S_n) \Rightarrow (\forall i \in [1,n] :S_1\Leftrightarrow S_i)$$

Given :

$$\forall i \in [1,n-1] : S_i\Leftrightarrow S_i+1$$

We will procede by recurrence (I'm not sure it's the correct english term):

Let $P_k = \{(S_1\Leftrightarrow S_k) \Leftrightarrow (S_1 \Leftrightarrow S_{k+1}) \} $

- Let $k=1$ :

  We know that $\tag{1}S_1 \Leftrightarrow S_2$ and $\tag{2}S_2 \Leftrightarrow S_3$ (those are given)

  $(1)$ and (2) allow us to conclude that $(S_1\Leftrightarrow S_2) \Rightarrow (S_1 \Leftrightarrow S_3)$ **and** $(S_1\Leftrightarrow S_3) \Rightarrow (S_1 \Leftrightarrow S_2)$ which is $P_1$ is true.
- Now suppose we have $P_k$ true for $k\in [1,n-2]$ which is :

  $$ (S_1\Leftrightarrow S_k) \Leftrightarrow (S_1 \Leftrightarrow S_{k+1}) $$

  But we also know (given) that :

  $$ S_{k+1} \Leftrightarrow S_{k+2}$$

  So we can conclude similary that :

$${\forall k \in [1,n-2] :P_k \Rightarrow P_{k+1}}$$

So now we proved $\forall k \in [1,n-1] : P_k$ (is true).

So we can conclude that if $S_1 \Leftrightarrow S_n$ then $\forall i\in [1,n] : S_1\Leftrightarrow S_i$